# Why does $\sin^4(\theta)+ \cos^4(\theta) +2\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)=1$?

Tags: trigonometry

Why does $$\sin^4(\theta)+ \cos^4(\theta) +2\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)=1$$ hold?

I feel like I'm missing some fancy application of trig identity which I already know. Or maybe there are really high level identities I do not know.

Comment: Do you know an identity featuring $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$?  That might be relevant here.

Comment: Yes I know of cos^2+sin^2 = 1
I don't see how to apply it though. Is it really that obvious?

Comment: Yes, it really is.  How do you get to fourth powers from squares?

Comment: Hint: $s^4+c^4+2s^2c^2$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Oh haha, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More in general, for any $x\in \mathbb R$

$$\left(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\theta\right)^x=1$$

How do we realistically discover/know this in practice? This is why we need to learn the fundamental binomial expansions

- $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$
- $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$
- $\ldots$

and others notable identities before than any other complicated formula.

---

**Edit**

If we can not recognize the binomial expansion for $n=2$, let use $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\theta=1$ to obtain

$$\sin^4 \theta+ \cos^4 \theta +2\cos^2 \theta\sin^2 \theta=$$

$$=(1-\cos^2\theta)^2+ \cos^4\theta +2\cos^2\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)=$$

$$1-2\cos^2\theta+\cos^4\theta+ \cos^4\theta +2\cos^2\theta-2\cos^4\theta=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$a^2+b^2+2ab=(a+b)^2.$$
Your question is of this form, with $a=\sin^2\theta$ and $b=\cos^2\theta$.

Use this to factorise the expression, and then use the identity $$\sin^2x+\cos^2x\equiv1.$$